# jquery in Rails 3.1.1 always gives DOMException

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I created a new app

```
rails new toy
cd toy
bundle install
rails generate controller start
rm public/index.html
```

`app/views/start/index.html.erb` contains:

```
Hi
```

`app/controllers/start_controller.rb` contains:

```
class StartController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb` is:

```
Toy::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'start#index'
end
```

If I run it and click anywhere on the page, I get errors in the debugger:

[image]

This happens on every app I run.

Here's the default Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Maybe you should try upgrading to Rails 3.1.7? (If Rails 3.2.x is out of the picture, that is)

Comment: @BenjaminTan, after spending a whole day messing with rvm, the problem remains in Rails 3.1.7

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this. Fixed it in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/33ce990ebb45f00813d2bee9658ac244ba1bc879).